# How to get the latest item created by a specific user by CAML query

Tags: c#, sharepoint, caml, splistitem

I am trying to get the most recent item created by a specific user by CAML query but it seems to return all the data created by everyone.

Help please.

Here's my code:

```
string lifestyleQuery = @"<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Author' /><Value Type='Text'>" + _id + @"</Value></Eq></Where>";
```

Comment: What is the value of the variable `_id`?

Comment: Try this tool to help you http://www.u2u.net/res/Tools/CamlQueryBuilder.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.Query = @"<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Author' LookupId='TRUE' /><Value Type='Integer'>" + _id + @"</Value></Eq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Created' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy>";
query.RowLimit = 1;
```

Comment: Dang beat me to it. This is exactly what she needs. :)